# Can anyone tell me why this white space is appearing in my jQuery mobile buttons?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I can't figure out how to get rid of this white line to the right of my buttons. Here's the problem:

http://cl.ly/image/2W0G1o2g3D47

Here's my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><html><style type="text/css">
        </style><head><title></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script></head><body>

        <div data-role="navbar" >
            <ul>
                <li><a id='button1' data-theme ="a" data-iconpos="top">Button 1</a></li>
                <li >  <a id='button2' data-theme ="a" data-iconpos="top">Button 2</a></li>
<li >  <a id='button3' data-theme ="a" data-iconpos="top">Button 3</a></li>
</ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->

        <div data-role="navbar" >
            <ul>
                <li><a id='button4' data-theme ="a" data-iconpos="top">Button 4</a></li>
                <li >  <a id='button5' data-theme ="a" data-iconpos="top">Button 5</a></li>

                <li >  <a id='button11' data-theme ="a" data-iconpos="top">Button 6     </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->

        <div data-role="navbar" >
            <ul>
                <li><a id='button6' data-theme ="a" data-iconpos="top">Button 7</a></li>
                <li >  <a id='button10' data-theme ="b" data-iconpos="top">Button 8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->

    </body></html>
```

Comment: He references the css in the HTML.  It's just JQuery Mobile - `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />`

Comment: Your buttons scale to the size of the container, so the width of the button is 33%.  That pixel you see is that extra 1%.
You don't see the pixel in the third row since both buttons scale to 50%.

Answer (score 1):

Set a class (ie class="lastbut") to the last button of each row.
Then, in CSS do this:

```
.lastbut {
   width:34% !important;
}
```

33%+33%+33% equals 99% and you see the white 1%
One of the buttons should be 34% if you want to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code in your CSS:

```
.ui-grid-b > :nth-child(n) {
   margin-right: 0px!important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i slolved this by using overflow-x:hidden on the navbar div :

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top" style="overflow-x:hidden">
```